# Rails 4 confuses class with module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, module

I have a model defined as:

```
class Phaxio

require 'rest_client'
require 'json'

attr_accessor :api_key, :secret_key, :callback_url, :current_intranet

def initialize(args)
    @current_intranet = args.fetch(:current_intranet)

    if Rails.env.production?
        @api_key      = current_intranet.settings.find_first_by_group_type_name("phaxio","api_key").try(:value)
        @secret_key   = current_intranet.settings.find_first_by_group_type_name("phaxio","api_secret").try(:value)
        @callback_url = "http://www.production.com/phaxio_holla_back"
    else
        @api_key      = current_intranet.settings.find_first_by_group_type_name("phaxio","api_key_test").try(:value)
        @secret_key   = current_intranet.settings.find_first_by_group_type_name("phaxio","api_secret_test").try(:value)
        @callback_url = "http://development.com:3002/phaxio_holla_back"
    end
end
```

There is no phaxio (or phaxios) table.  The model is named "phaxio.rb."  I do not have a phaxios_controller.

When I call `Phaxio.new(current_intranet)`, I get "undefined method `new' for Phaxio:Module".  I do not have a Phaxio module and I've done a grep on my app (it's quite large) to make sure that "Phaxio" isn't defined somewhere else.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

No, the application is not named "Phaxio".  My application.rb is:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)
module V2
   class Application < Rails::Application
      config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/presenters/*"].find_all { |f| File.stat(f).directory? }
      config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/services/*"].find_all { |f| File.stat(f).directory? }
      config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/queries/*"].find_all { |f| File.stat(f).directory? }
      config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/*"].find_all { |f| File.stat(f).directory? }
      config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

      $TECH_EMAIL     = ["fhock@production.com", "wprince@production.com"]

      config.to_prepare do
         Devise::SessionsController.layout "sessions"
         #Devise::RegistrationsController.layout "sessions"
         #Devise::ConfirmationsController.layout "sessions"
         #Devise::UnlocksController.layout "sessions"            
         Devise::PasswordsController.layout "sessions"
      end
   end
end

require 'tools'
require 'pdf_tools'
```

Comment: Any chance that your application is also named 'Phaxio' ? What's in your config/application.rb ?

Comment: It would be interesting to see what executing `Phaxio.inspect` in rails console would return.

Answer (score 0):

On a last resort suggestion from a friend, I renamed all references to phaxio to phaxio2 and all was well.  No idea why that made a difference as I had run a grep to find all instances of the word "phaxio" in case there was some conflicting module, but none was found.  I guess sometimes grasping at straws does work!